# How do I get OnFocusChangeListener to listen again after Device Rotation?

Tags: android, android-edittext, focus

I have an EditText that launches a DatePickerDialog fragment when it gains focus or is clicked on.  It works fine.  However, after device rotation the OnFocus listener no longer launches the fragment. The focus is moved to the EditText line but the cursor just blinks and the dialog does not launch.  Any ideas?  Do I need to put some additional code in onResume?

Activity file:

```
fEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {  
       if (hasFocus && (fEditText.getText().length() == 0) && (savedInstanceState  == null)) {
        DatePickerFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
        newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
       }
    }
});
```

Layout file:

```
<LinearLayout

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
tools:context=".Activity">

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/DueDate_text_input_layout"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  >

<com.example...EditText
    android:id="@+id/FEditText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="date"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" >

</com.example...EditText>
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below inside `onResume()` instead of `onCreate()` of `Activity` or `onCreateView` of `fragment`

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();         

    fEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {  
       if (hasFocus && (fEditText.getText().length() == 0) && (savedInstanceState  == null)) {
        DatePickerFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
        newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
       }
    }
  });    
}
```

Comment: Android Studio says Variable "onConfigurationChanged" is never used.

Comment: Had to remove the "&& (savedInstance == null) code.  I thought that would do it but it did not work.  Any ideas?

Comment: Ok, it does works for when length() ==0.  So now I just need to do an else statement for length()>0.

Comment: Is your dialogue is being launched ?

Comment: Yes, all good.  Putting the OnFocusChangeListener in onResume worked.  Thank you, answer accepted and upvoted.  Cheers.